# Replace a script with another using Js and checkbox?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm creating a page which is suppose to be a little interactive. The user is suppose to be able to change a bunch of information by checking off an checkbox.

Index.php:

```
<span id="changeIt">Deactivated! - [ChangeMod]<img src="pic/deactivated.png"></span>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxChange"  onclick="ChangeEverything();">Change Everything!</input>
</form>

<script TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="script/map_checkbox.js"></script>
```

map_checkbox.js:

```
    var checkbox6 = document.getElementById("checkboxChange");
    var posting6 = document.getElementById("changeIt");
    var script = document.createElement("scriptChange");

    function ChangeEverything(){
        if (checkbox6.checked){
    posting6.innerHTML="Activated! - [ChangeMod]<img src='pic/activated.png'>" ;
    script.src = 'scriptMain.js';
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(scriptChange);
        }
    else{
    posting6.innerHTML="Deactivated! - [ChangeMod]<img src='pic/deactivated.png'>" ;
    script.src = 'scriptSec.js';
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(scriptChange);
    }
    }
```

Is it possible to overwrite the script like this, or do I have to use another method?

Comment: You could  use require.js

Comment: How? sorry, I'm still fairly 'green' at this still:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have a problem with the

```
    var script = document.createElement("scriptChange");
```

tou have to put the tag NAME

```
    var script = document.createElement("script");
```